# How can I test if a marketing effort was successful?

Tags: statistical-significance, marketing

I looked at a test group (West Coast pop) versus a control group (non West Coast) and took independent samples pre-message and post message for each group.  I measured awareness (top-3 box of a 5-pt scale) for each of the 4 independent samples.

I looked at lift (in percentage points) for test group and lift for the control group.

What is the statistical test for significance between test and control groups to determine whether or not the marketing messaging got through?

Comment: Is the outcome binary, aware or not?